# Remove all \n from a string from within a character in the text

Tags: javascript

Assuming that we have this variable string

```
const str = "address2\r\nmultiple1,\"my address row 1\nmy address row 2\",12345,\"my address 22222 row 1\nmy address 2222 row 2\"\r\n"
```

How to remove all the `\n` that is within the character `\"`?
Maybe through a regex?

Expected Output should be

```
str = "address2\r\nmultiple1,my address row 1 my address row 2,12345,my address 22222 row 1 my address 2222 row 2\r\n"
```

Comment: Do you want to remove only `\n`, or also carriage returns `\r` ?

Comment: Use `String.replace()` and pass `regex` as param.

Comment: what's expected output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just the `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex -

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/3xGR6e/1)

```js
const str = "companyaddress2\r\nmultiple1,\"my address row 1\nmy address row 2\",12345,\"my address 22222 row 1\nmy address 2222 row 2\"\r\n";
const regex = new RegExp('(\\")([^\\n]*)(\\n)([^\\n]*)(\\")', 'g');
const newStr = str.replaceAll(regex, '$2 $4');
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: What does `$2 $4` mean?

Comment: They are the sequence number of the matched groups in the regex. The regex  has 5 groups enclosed in `()`. of that 1,3 and 5 are the ones that needs replacement and $2 $4 need to be kept same. 1 and 5 are completely removed and the 2 one is replaced with space, therefore -$2 $4. You can check the regex link for more explanation and also here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
str.replaceAll("\n", "");
```

Comment: This won't meet the spec - it will remove them all, regardless of position within string